# jQuery Add Collapsible Panel

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery I want to dynamically add new collapsible panels. An accordion is not enough, as I need to have more than one section open at a time.

The sample [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/24708866/labs/jquery-multi-open-accordion/index.html) is exactly what I need apart from I'm wanting a button click to dynamically add a new panel.

Using .append() to add in a new  tag doesn't work. I don't mind if the solution includes plugins or whatever (I don't want to use a framework such as 'KendoUI' though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in the [jQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion):

> An accordion doesn't allow more than one content panel to be open at
>   the same time, and it takes a lot of effort to do that. If you are
>   looking for a widget that allows more than one content panel to be
>   open, don't use this. Usually it can be written with a few lines of
>   jQuery instead, something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $('.accordion .head').click(function() {
      $(this).next().toggle();
      return false;
  }).next().hide();
});
Or animated:

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $('.accordion .head').click(function() {
      $(this).next().toggle('slow');
      return false;
  }).next().hide();
})
```

;

Comment: Please be sure to properly attribute outside sources that you draw text from.